# Bootstrap grid not appearing correctly on 24 inch monitor

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Strange issue here.  I'm employing a bootstrap grid

```html
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-10"></div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
```

For my portfolio.  On my laptop, which has a monitor of perhaps 16 inches, this looks fine.  However, on my 24-inch monitor, the middle section looks oddly small, like it spans 8 columns instead of ten.  Any idea why this would be?  It is all inside a container class div.

EDIT: Here's how it looks.  And here's a [link](https://dennismarkham.github.io/ConceptPortfolio/)

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you see if the two monitors?  Also, can you convert your code into a [mre] for faster troubleshooting?  I am unsure if the amount of code provided correctly shows the issue you are describing

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wasn't sure how much code I'd need to reproduce the error, and I didn't want to get in trouble for putting too much.

Comment: There's still not enough code but I believe that instead of `.container`, you need to use `.container-fluid` .  `.container` has a max width of 1320px ([See Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/)) while `.container-fluid` has a max width of 100% and will span the entire width of the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`

The latter has a max width of 1320px while the former has a max width of 100% and will span the entire width of the viewport.

See the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/)

See sample code below (expand to full page to see it better)

```css
div{
   border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">a</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">middle</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the the grid size depending on screen size.
This may help you. just add 3 grid type class for screen size -

**sm** for small screen,

**md** for medium screen and

**lg** for large screen

you only need to increase greed size for large screen.

Hope this will work for your problem.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Solution</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 bg-warning">a</div>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-12 bg-primary">middle</div>
          <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 bg-warning">b</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will not fix OPs issue (at all)